# How to do command substitution in text file with bash

Tags: bash

How to do command substitution in text file using bash. Is there any command which treats text files (possible strings) like here documents?

```sh
# export NAME=John
# cat <<'EOF' > template
Hello, ${NAME}
Date: $(date)
EOF
# some-magic < template
Hello, ${NAME}
Date: Fri 02 Aug 2019 04:01:48 PM CEST
```

I know, `envsubst` does variable substitution, but not command substitution.

```sh
# envsubst < template 
Hello, John
Date: $(date)
```

The expected output is similar to here documents behavior w/o `NAME` expanded.

```sh
# export NAME=John
# cat <<EOF
Hello, ${NAME}
Date: $(date)
EOF
Hello, John
Date: Fri 02 Aug 2019 04:01:48 PM CEST
```

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Do you also *create* the file using a here-doc, or do you have a file that already contains command substitutions? In the former case, you can just not quote the `EOF` marker to have things expand.

Comment: i already have file containing command substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:
`` echo -e "$(eval "echo -e \"`<FILE`\"")" ``

Example:

```
$ cat FILE
Using: ${SHELL}
Date: $(date)
$ echo -e "$(eval "echo -e \"`<FILE`\"")"
Using: /bin/bash
Date: Fri Aug  2 10:06:59 PDT 2019
```

Explanation:
Substitute the entire input file into the command with `` echo -e \"`<FILE`\" ``, `eval`uate it (to perform command/variable substitution), then `echo` with command sequences to preserve the original newlines and such.

Comment: It would be better to `eval` a here document, that way you won't have issues with quotes and backslashes

Comment: it seems, that simple ``eval "echo -e \"`<FILE`\""`` does the job. thanks.